# Enable captions freeze image with receiver Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have a problem with the chromecast receiver,
I reproduce without problems the video that is a format DRM (PlayReady)
Integrate lincensies (licenseUrl, licenseCustomData), this part I have no problem.

The problem I have at the time of activating the subtitles and changing the audio of the video, from my Android sender the video is frozen in both cases.

I am using the reciver example that is in github: https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer

Sender Android these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

And the configuration of the mediaInfo is as follows:

```
private MediaInfo buildMediaInfo() {
    MediaMetadata movieMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_GENERIC);

    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "STORKS");
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "CIGÜEÑAS: LA HISTORIA QUE NO TE CONTARON");
    movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("https://d1id64irsb2xux.cloudfront.net/images/3edaea38ef1a46bfab6b977ecb490378_192X288.jpg")));
    movieMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("https://d1id64irsb2xux.cloudfront.net/images/3edaea38ef1a46bfab6b977ecb490378_192X288.jpg")));

    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("customDataPR", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        jsonObj.put("licenseServer", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to add description to the json object", e);
    }

    return new MediaInfo.Builder("http://d1fvtwjxzaawfl.cloudfront.net/usp-s3-storage/clear/zootopia/zootopia.ism/Manifest")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_NONE)
            .setContentType("application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml")
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
            .setCustomData(jsonObj)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you follow up and provide the info that is requested on the SDK issue tracker for the ticket that you have opened there.

Comment: @AliNaddaf What change are required in the above code if I've to use the same receiver application for playing widevine ?